# php loading api very slow

Tags: php, api, include

I have this code, as a php file, I include it in the index and presenting the BTC/ETH values, the site loading is very slow, any suggestion what can I do so it run faster? maybe I do something wrong here with the code, im new with json :).

Thanks for helping!

```
    <?php

function getCryptoPrices($url)
{
    $decode = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($decode, true);
}

/* BTC USD */
$BTC_USD = getCryptoPrices('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');
$BTC_VALUE = $BTC_USD['last'];

/* ETH USD */
$ETH_USD = getCryptoPrices('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/ethusd/');
$ETH_VALUE = $ETH_USD['last'];


session_start();

$_SESSION['BTC'] = $BTC_VALUE;
$_SESSION['ETH'] = $ETH_VALUE;

?>
```

Comment: You should use curl API call in php. Right now your approach is not correct.

Comment: Reaching out to another site (twice in this case) is always going to be slow.  Depending on how up to date you want the results, you could cache the last value and only reload them if they are too old.

Comment: @AravindBhatK _“You should use curl API call in php. Right now your approach is not correct.”_ - please don’t make such statement without any proof or supporting argument. file_get_contents can be used to make standard HTTP requests perfectly fine in most cases; it doesn’t always “need” cURL for trivial stuff like this. Saying _“your approach is not correct”_ in this case because the are not using cURL, is just nonsense.

Comment: I agree to your comment.@misorude

Comment: @NigelRen how can i make it better? told so im newbie to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can user CURL for read content in urls very fast.. you must install "curl" in your server if it's not there then try this function .

```
$returned_content = get_data('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');
```

The Code

```
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```